# Simple and performant way to proxy and wrap method calls

Tags: python

What I'm trying to achieve is to wrap specific method calls of a class with a method of its subclass. I could do this one by one, like this:

```
class Subclass(ParentClass):
    def _handle_response(self, data, _suppress=None):
        # process data
        return data

    def foo(self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
        return self._handle_response(super().foo(*a, **kw), _suppress=_suppress)

    def bar(self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
        return self._handle_response(super().bar(*a, **kw), _suppress=_suppress)
```

But since there are ~20 methods that need to be wrapped this way, it strikes me as quite redundant.
Another way I've come up with is to use `__getattribute__` like this:

```
class Subclass(ParentClass):
    def _handle_response(self, data, _suppress=None):
        # process data
        return data

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr in {"foo", "bar"}:
            def wrapped(_self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
                return self._handle_response(
                    getattr(ParentClass, attr)(_self, *a, **kw),
                    _suppress=_suppress
                )
            return wrapped
        return super().__getattribute__(attr)
```

This works but I'm not really happy with the fact that each time a method is called like this, a new wrapper function is created. This a lot of unnecessary overhead that I'd like to avoid. I *could* cache these, but again, this seems to be not a very elegant solution.

Anyone has an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Where is the overhead in this? I am assuming this is part of a network call. So at any point only one of the methods will be wrapped in a new created function. cmiiw.

Comment: If I'm not completely mistaken on how `__getattribute__` works, in this example, every call to `foo` will create a new `wrapper` function.
I tested it by adding a `wrappers_created` class variable to `Subclass`
and adding the following line to `__getattribute__` before returning the wrapper: `Subclass.wrappers_created += 1`. After 2 calls to `foo`, the counter is at `2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3546120/4983469

Comment: @leoOrion: That does not apply here since a decorator is called *once* when the function is created. The question you linked is about how much overhead the wrapper creates. What I'm talking about is the overhead of creating the wrapper.
Afaik a decorator does not create a new wrapper on each function call to the decorated function.

Comment: I added that to suggest the idea of decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are created during runtime so you can still modify them after the declaration and add the methods you want.

```
class ParentClass():
    def foo(self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
        return "foo"

    def bar(self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
        return "bar"

class Subclass(ParentClass):
    def _handle_response(self, data, _suppress=None):
        return data + " plus"

methods_to_wrap = ["foo", "bar"]

for method in methods_to_wrap:
    def make_wrapper(m):
        def wrap(self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
            return self._handle_response(getattr(super(type(self), self), m)(*a, **kw), _suppress=_suppress)
        return wrap
    setattr(Subclass, method, make_wrapper(m=method))

o = Subclass()
print(o.foo())
print(o.bar())
```

prints

```
foo plus
bar plus
```

The reason I am using the `make_wrapper` function is to avoid [late binding](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures). The rest should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although I didn't end up implementing it exactly like this your answer has helped me to find a satisfying solution! I tried to achieve something similar by modifying the `__new__` method, but kept running into various errors. What I had done differently was mainly the lookup of the parent class' original method, and I didn't address the late binding problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is how I ended up solving the problem based on [zxzak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62880038/7733079).

```
class Subclass(ParentClass):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        for method in ("foo", "bar", ...):
            def make_wrapper(m):
                def wrap(self, *a, _suppress=None, **kw):
                    return self._handle_response(getattr(super(type(self), self), m)(*a, **kw), _suppress=_suppress)
                return wrap
            setattr(cls, method, make_wrapper(m=method))
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```